# I have an external json file ,say abc.json. in that it contain { "remember me": "Acuérdate " }

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$.get("resources-locale_fr.json", function(data) {

    for (var key in data) {

        if (key == data1) {
            console.log("sijilal" + data[key]);
            $scope.englishText = data[key];
            $scope.$digest();

        }

    }
});
```

example if i enter ["remember me"] i will get  "Acuérdate ".
My problem is i need to edit this " "Acuérdate "" to  "Acuérdate123 " and need to save it to my external json abc.json.am using localhost.answers in angularjs is much appreciated.

Here data1 is the key name i enetered and i will get its corresponding value.
It will retrieve the correct word (value) for the key i entered,but problem is i need to edit the value name and need to save that to external json file.

Is there any way to save value to corresponding pair in external json

Comment: @rioc ,am trying in my local,so my local abc.json need to be reflected.I dont want to send to server side and all. I need to edit and update my local abc.json

Comment: @rioc0719.I dont have server. User give key name,it will automaticall fetch value name from json,we are giving provision to user to edit that particular value for that key ,it should save in that local json text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the data you need to do two things:

**On the client** you need to send the changed data back to the server. This will typically be done with a POST request.

For example:

```
$.post("resources-locale_fr.fcgi", { "remember me", updated_variable });
```

**On the server** you will need some server side code, written in the language of your choice, that accepts the POST request and writes the data to the file (usually after performing some authentication/authorization check).

For this sort of application you would usually replace the static JSON file with a database and then generate JSON on demand with a server side program.

Comment: @midhunk — Why are you shouting at me to ask if this answer answers your question? Of course it will, there wouldn't be any point in giving an answer if it didn't achieve your goal.

Comment: ,am trying in my local,so my local abc.json need to be reflected.I dont want to send to server side and all. I need to edit and update my local abc.json

Comment: example if i enter ["remember me"] i will get "Acuérdate ". My problem is i need to edit this " "Acuérdate "" to "Acuérdate123 " and need to save it to my external json abc.json.am using localhost.answers in angularjs is much appreciated. **All i am trying in my local file,no server is there,i have a local file abc.json,in that i need to edit the value name**

Comment: Wait wait, you need your user to edit this value? User edits from browser?

Comment: @surajck exactly.but i dont have server.  **User give key name,it will automaticall fetch value name from json,we are giving provision to user  to edit that particular value for that key ,it should save in that local json text file**

Comment: Not possible. You cannot **modify** the files in your computer from browser. You will need a server, only a server can access and save

Comment: @surajck ,browser means local file ,its a html file ,and my json is also local file,am running in wamp server.

Comment: @surajck both my files are local files one is html file that allow user to fetch the value name and edit the value name and the other is local json file from where i fetch the value and where i need to save the newly edited value

Comment: Wamp only serves your files, you still cannot edit the base file from your browser unless you go through a server

Comment: @midhunk — You have to write the server code I described in the answer. Web servers do not allow arbitrary clients to overwrite arbitrary files on their disks, that would be a horrific security problem.    If you are using WAMP then you can do that in PHP out of the box, or install something else (like Perl, Python or Ruby) and access that via FastCGI or some other API provided for allowing web servers to run programs in response to requests.